# The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" exited with code 2.Asp.Net Core Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

So I started working with Asp.Net Core Angular application.But I am having some problem publishing the application.I tried creating a publish profile but the publish seems to fail each time.'The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod" exited with code 2' is the error message.If there is any key step that should not missed while publishing asp,net core angular application for example 'npm install ..' and stuffs please let me know.Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you should run this command in command line. Maybe describe the error in better format as in VS.

Comment: you use custom webpack.config?

Comment: No I just went on to publish.First it was saying something like "the npm install exited with code 2".Then I ran the npm install code in cmd with my current project directory set.And the ran into this error.

Comment: Do you install nodejs and angular cli on your computer?

Comment: The general publish procedure in VS, when create a new angular app is very simple. Just right click on project and “publish”, so i dont imagine that what your problem. Which folder do you publish to?